# Are there dynamically-typed functional languages?

Tags: types, functional-programming, programming-languages, dynamic-typing

This is essentially the opposite of this question: [Are there statically-typed functional languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8147328/200783)

The only dynamically-typed functional languages mentioned in that question are "Lisp family languages (Common Lisp, Scheme, Clojure)".

Are there any other dynamically-typed functional languages?

Comment: None of your mentioned languages are purely funcitonal. You can program in a functional way with most languages and typing and paradigms don't really couple so tight. You also have loose and strict typing where the LISPs are strict while JavaScript, Perl and PHP are loose since if you try to add a number and a string LISP would require explicit cast while in the loose languages magic happens and you might not like the answer.

Comment: Functional programming doesn't depend on a particular type system. Strict type systems just guarantee that a certain type of errors doesn't occur during run-time. To be used in a functional manner, a language requires merely first class/higher order functions.

Comment: Groovy is a candidate. Smalltalk, IMHO is a candidate too.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang is a mostly functional language (although not purely functional) and is dynamically typed.

Many other languages support functional programming to some degree and have a dynamic type system:

- Clojure
- Smalltalk

... to name a few. The key features of these languages are:

- functions are first class (may be passed around as values)
- data is mostly immutable
- referential transparent functions (i.e., functions do not mutate state).

Most practical languages still support some imperative constructs which may be used when the functional paradigm does not fit the problem (lots of classical data structures require mutation of state. Equivalent functional structures are not always available) or when performance favors mutation of data in-place.

Answer (score 0):

For a purely-functional dynamically typed language, there is [BLC (Binary Lambda Calculus)](https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html). This language works by defining the program as a transformation of a stream, just like Haskell before monadic IO or even continuation-based IO is introduced. This stream is then church-encoded so it can be embedded in lambda calculus.
That said, this language is actually esoteric, and a turing tarpit one to the boot, so it has no practical usage.